# Get date/time of last reboot programmatically

Tags: c++, c, linux, reboot

I would like to find the time of the last reboot programmatically in Linux. I am using C and C++ in my module.

Is there an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct api, but you can read `/proc/uptime` "file" to learn how many seconds the system have been running, subtract that from the current time - and assume that's when the machine was rebooted.

> /proc/uptime
>                 This file contains two numbers: the uptime of the system
>   (seconds), and the amount of time
>   spent in idle process (seconds).

Answer (score 5):

You could either invoke [`uptime`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uptime) or take a look at [`/proc/uptime`](http://www.linuxinsight.com/proc_uptime.html). Given the current time, and knowing how long the system's been up allows you to calculate the time of the last reboot.

Alternatively, the `btime` entry in `/proc/stat` gives the boot time directly (in seconds since the epoch) -- search [`man proc`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) for `btime`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can find the last reboot time by reading the /var/log/wtmp file. This is a binary file but you can parse with it (or your C version of it)

http://pastebin.com/nSVw82cZ

[WARNING! terrible coding style!]