# Get the boot time in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, boot

how can i get the boot time of ios in objective c ?

Is there a way to get it?

Comment: boot time? You mean app launch time?

Comment: Try using [`clock()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/). I am unsure what it returns in iOS, but it's part of the standard library, so it has a reasonable chance of doing what it shouold.

Comment: @tipycalFlow no, i meant the ios launch time (the operating system). thanks

Comment: @Youssef Don't think that's possible...not sure, though.

Comment: you mean something like /proc/uptime in linux? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4972651/550177

Comment: @phix23 yes that's what I'm looking for but in IOS not linux. thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't know if this will work in iOS, but in OS X (which is essentially the same OS) you would use [sysctl()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/sysctl.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/sysctl).  This is how the OS X Unix utility `uptime` does it.  [Source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-149/w/w.c?txt) is available - search for "boottime".

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>  

// ....  

#define MIB_SIZE 2  

int mib[MIB_SIZE];
size_t size;
struct timeval  boottime;

mib[0] = CTL_KERN;
mib[1] = KERN_BOOTTIME;
size = sizeof(boottime);
if (sysctl(mib, MIB_SIZE, &boottime, &size, NULL, 0) != -1)
{
    // successful call
    NSDate* bootDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:boottime.tv_sec];
}
```

The restricted nature of programming in the iOS sandboxed environment might make it not work, I don't know, I haven't tried it.

Comment: There are apps in the App Store that are using sysctl functionality.  Doesn't necessarily mean this would be allowed though.

Comment: seems to work, I edited the answer to show how to get it as NSDate

Comment: It is absolutely allowed on the app store

Comment: A good reason to use it: boot time changes obviously when you reboot, but also if the user changes the clock. So to check that your time is reliable, you store the last known boot time in preferences, and if that time changes, who can check with a time server whether the time is ok. iOS keeps the "seconds since boot" unchanged except for the obvious change of one second each second, even when you change the clock in settings.

Answer (score 1):

I took JeremyP's answer, gave the result the full microsecond precision, clarified the names of local variables, improved the order, and put it into a method:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>  

// ....  

+ (nullable NSDate *)bootDate
{
    // nameIntArray and nameIntArrayLen
    int nameIntArrayLen = 2;
    int nameIntArray[nameIntArrayLen];
    nameIntArray[0] = CTL_KERN;
    nameIntArray[1] = KERN_BOOTTIME;

    // boot_timeval
    struct timeval boot_timeval;
    size_t boot_timeval_size = sizeof(boot_timeval);
    if (sysctl(nameIntArray, nameIntArrayLen, &boot_timeval, &boot_timeval_size, NULL, 0) == -1)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    // bootSince1970TimeInterval
    NSTimeInterval bootSince1970TimeInterval = (NSTimeInterval)boot_timeval.tv_sec + ((NSTimeInterval)boot_timeval.tv_usec / 1000000);

    // return
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:bootSince1970TimeInterval];
}
```